# Problem of getting variable from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

Stackoverflow, hello.

I need to take a variable (list) from my function. However, I can't do this and the result is an empty [], despite I have the exactly same process for another function and I CAN get the variable from there.

The code:

```
 cook_book={}
dishnumber=[]
dishnames_string = []
ingridient_names_final=[]
ingridient_quantity=[]
ingridient_measure=[]
ingridient_names = []

def dishnumbersearch():
    with open ('recipes.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            # print (line)
            line2=line.split()
            try:
                a=int(list(line2[0])[0])
                dishnumber.append(a)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            except IndexError:
                pass
            except ValueError:
                pass

dishnumbersearch()

def namesearch():
    with open ('recipes.txt') as f:
        dishnames = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            # print (line)
            line2=line.split()
            if len(line2) <= 3:
                pass
                try:
                    a=(int(line2[0])/1)
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                except ValueError:
                    dishnames.append(line2)
        for i in dishnames:
            if len(i) > 1:
                j=' '.join(i)
            else:
                j = str(i[0])
            dishnames_string.append(j)

namesearch()

def search_ingridientsnames():
    with open('recipes.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            # print (line)
            line2 = line.split()
            try:
                i=0
                if len(line2) > 3 or len(line2)<1:
                    ingridient_names.append(line2[0])
            except IndexError:
                ingridient_names.append('_')
    from itertools import groupby
    ingridient_names_final=[list(g) for k, g in groupby(ingridient_names, key=lambda i: i != '_') if k]
    print(ingridient_names_final)

search_ingridientsnames()

print(dishnames_string)
print (ingridient_names_final)
```

The result:

```
[['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'], ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy'], ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda'], ['Beef', 'Sweet', 'Pita', 'Wine', 'Tomato']]
['Omelette', 'Peking Duck', 'Baked potato', 'Fajitos']
[]
```

So, you see, in first case `print(dishnames_string)` I can take a variable from the function, in second case `print (ingridient_names_final)` the variable is only could be recieved INSIDE the function.

P.S. By the way, If i delete `print (ingridient_names_final)` inside the function - also an empty brackets.

'recipes.txt' is here:

```
Omelette
3
Egg | 2 | PCS
Milk | 100 | ml
Tomato | 2 | PCS

Peking Duck
4
Duck | 1 | PCS
Water | 2 | l
Honey | 3 | tbsp
Soy sauce | 60 | ml

Baked potato
3
Potato | 1 | kg
Garlic | 3 | cog
Gouda cheese | 100 | g

Fajitos
5
Beef | 500 | g
Sweet pepper | 1 | PCS
Pita bread | 2 | PCS
Wine Vinegar | 1 | tbsp
Tomato | 2 | PCS
```

Comment: Don't use global variables like this. Each function should *return* a list, rather than mutating a previously created list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to reassign a global variable within a function, you need to define it locally using the `global` keyword.

```py
def search_ingridientsnames():
    global ingridient_names_final
    with open('recipes.txt') as f:
        # process data
    from itertools import groupby
    ingridient_names_final=[list(g) for k, g in groupby(ingridient_names, key=lambda i: i != '_') if k]
```